# Android return from browser to app

Tags: android, browser

I have option in my app to start browser and load imdb website.
I'm using ActionView for this.

```
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(website));

        try {
            activity.startActivity(intent1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.no_imdb, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
```

The problem occurs when I tap on back button.
When default browser app is launched everything is ok.
When Opera Mini app is launched, when I tap on back button, it seems like my app receives two back actions, and finish my current activity.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try starting the intent in a new task:

```
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Or

```
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); WORKS PERFECT! Tnx for idea!

Answer (score 5):

Please add this code to your android manifest for activity that you need return

```
    <activity
        android:name="YourActivityName"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="schemas.your_package.YourActivityName" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and add this to your web page

```html
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=schemas.your_package.YourActivityName;end">click to load app</a>
```

because only one app has this action name (schemas.your_package.YourActivityName) on your phone, web page directly return to app

Comment: دمت گرم آقا میلاد مشکل من حل شد با این کد

Comment: greate ... tnx sir 

Answer (score 1):

Also You can Use [Airbnb DeepLink lib](https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch)

**Example**

Here's an example where we register SampleActivity to pull out an ID from a deep link like example://example.com/deepLink/123. We annotated with @DeepLink and specify there will be a parameter that we'll identify with id.

```
@DeepLink("example://example.com/deepLink/{id}")
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(DeepLink.IS_DEEP_LINK, false)) {
      Bundle parameters = intent.getExtras();
      String idString = parameters.getString("id");
      // Do something with idString
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.